# Trouble mutating new column using case_when in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I would like to mutate a new column using different length values from the Código column on [this](http://www.arcotel.gob.ec/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/proyeccion_cantonal_total_2010-2020_seg%C3%BAn_INEC1.ods) dataframe.

```r
ods <- readODS::read_ods('http://www.arcotel.gob.ec/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/proyeccion_cantonal_total_2010-2020_seg%C3%BAn_INEC1.ods', skip = 2)
```

I've tried using case_when inside a mutate like this:

```r
mutate(ods, Provincia = case_when(
        length(ods$Código) == 3 ~ str_extract(ods$Código, '[[:digit:]]{1}'),
        length(ods$Código) == 4 ~ str_extract(ods$Código, '[[:digit:]]{2}')
))
```

It's supposed to create a new Provincia column with the first digit from Código whenever the length of its value is 3, otherwise should extract two digits. When running the above code I only get NA's

Comment: i think you want `nchar` here and not `length`

Comment: Excelente! Would you turn your comment as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nchar`, which will count the number of characters in each observation:

```
ods <- mutate(ods, Provincia = case_when(
         nchar(ods$Código) == 3 ~ str_extract(ods$Código, '[[:digit:]]{1}'),
         nchar(ods$Código) == 4 ~ str_extract(ods$Código, '[[:digit:]]{2}')
 ))
```

Result:

```
    > ods %>% pull(Provincia)
  [1] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
 [22] "2"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "5" 
 [43] "6"  "6"  "6"  "6"  "6"  "6"  "6"  "6"  "6"  "6"  "7"  "7"  "7"  "7"  "7"  "7"  "7"  "7"  "7"  "7"  "7" 
 [64] "7"  "7"  "7"  "8"  "8"  "8"  "8"  "8"  "8"  "8"  "8"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9" 
 [85] "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "9"  "10" "10" "10" "10" "10" "10"
[106] "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "11" "12" "12" "12" "12" "12"
[127] "12" "12" "12" "12" "12" "12" "12" "12" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13"
[148] "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "13" "14" "14" "14" "14" "14" "14" "14" "14" "14" "14" "14" "14"
[169] "15" "15" "15" "15" "15" "16" "16" "16" "16" "17" "17" "17" "17" "17" "17" "17" "17" "18" "18" "18" "18"
[190] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "20" "20" "20" "21" "21" "21" "21"
[211] "21" "21" "21" "22" "22" "22" "22" "23" "24" "24" "24" "90" "90" "90"
```